# Table of Content appears as Inhaltsverzeichnis, Chapter as Kapitel

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using Rmarkdown to write a report. When I compile the markdown which has multiple pages and/or chapters, I get header printed as German language. How do I change that to English
Specifically, Inhaltsverzeichnis to Table of Content , Kapitel  to Chapter

My index.md

```
---
title: "Title of Work "
author: |
        | by
        | Author
  
subtitle: |
          | 
          | Submitted to Graduate faculty 
          | of 
          | 
          | in Partial Requirement of 
          | The Requirements for the Degree 
          | of 
          |  
          | 
          | 
          | Committee
          | _______________________        Prof. Person 1, Committee Member 
          |
          | _______________________        Prof. Person 1, Committee Member
          | 
          | _______________________        Prof. Person 3, Committee Member
          |
          | _______________________        Prof. Person 4, Committee Member

      

site: bookdown::bookdown_site
#output: bookdown::pdf_book

output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex  #pdflatex #xelatex #lualatex
    #toc: no
    #toc_depth: 3
    #toc_float: true
    #number_sections: true
    keep_tex: true
    fig_caption: true
    df_print: kable
  
    extra_dependencies: ["adjustbox", "subfig"]

editor_options:
  markdown:
    wrap: sentence

header-includes:
   - \usepackage{amssymb}
   - \usepackage{amsmath}
   - \usepackage{subfig}
   - \usepackage{algorithm2e}
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \usepackage{booktabs}
   - \usepackage{colortbl}
   - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   - \usepackage{multirow}
   - \usepackage{rotating}
   - \usepackage{textcomp}
   - \usepackage{polyglossia}
   - \setotherlanguage{greek}
   - \usepackage{mathtools}
   
mainfont: Arial
fontsize: 10pt
linestretch: 1.5
subparagraph: yes
documentclass: report
bibliography: [book.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
#geometry: margin=5cm
geometry: "left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
description: "Thesis Description"
---
```

What is the correct process also to separate out the Title Page from Index?

Comment: I'd guess you have an environment variable set saying R should work in German.  Try `Sys.getenv("LANGUAGE")` and see if it gives "de" or similar.  If that's not it, you probably have something similar affecting LaTeX.

Comment: It returns empty string. Looked almost every where from all configs, etc. Can't find any bug that says "de". Interestingly enough, only header is German remaning text is English.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll have to make the full document available for others to look at.

Comment: Thanks user2554330, will keep looking. unfortunately wont be able to share all code here

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "a full document".  You don't need to share the real thing, just a full document that exhibits the behaviour you want to fix.  Without that, you're just wasting everyone's time (including your own).